# typescript error: TS2304: Cannot find name '$'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

The statement

```
 x = $('#msgBox_' + scope.boxId).position().left;
```

generates an

> error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'

although `jquery` and `@types` are installed in the node_modules folder.

My tsconfig.json looks like that:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: How do you access `$` in your code? As a global variable?

Comment: Could you please add your tsconfig.json?

Comment: Try to remove the include part.

Comment: What version of ts are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the "@types/jquery" node module, which contains a definition of "$". Once I added "@types/jquery": "^3.2.5" to the list of  "devDependencies" in my package.json and reinstalled via "npm install", everything worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

Did you try to :

```
 import $ = require('jquery');
```

at the 1 line? This should work.
Though you should have a deeper look into es6 modules and ts modules to get a grip on how you could take advantage of the es6 modular system. Also d.ts files...

This should be helpful:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: at the 1st line of which file?

Comment: The ones where you use jquery.

Comment: Due to current tsconfig.json, this should not be required. Jquery is defined also as a global var, you have to import it only if the "isolatedModules" flag is true.

Comment: Actually, it fixes the bug. However: In a previous version of the same code, this import was not necessary. I currentyl don't really understand, why I need it now.

Comment: @OctoD How and where would I best define jquery as a global var in a typescript project?

Comment: It is not defined as a global variable... It is only installed as a node_module. Also you should install @types/jquery if you havent.

Comment: you could make it global like this
window.$ = $; But this is bad practice i guess...

Comment: @user1934212 it's defined both as global or module inside the types definition
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts you should do nothing.

Comment: @OctoD: Interesting point. I just looked into my node_"modules/@types" folder and there is no "jquery" subfolder.  How can I fix that?

Comment: Try to run npm i --save-dev @types/jquery.

Answer (score 8):

If AngularCLI is where your injecting JQuery, then in your controller/component, you can declare the variable like so:

```
declare var $: any;
```

Comment: I had moved some code from an Angular 2+ solution to an Angular 6 solution and this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this kind of error is your *node_modules* doesn't contain the type definitions for jquery ie. the package `@types/jquery` is missing.

My workaround is as follows:

1. Open the command prompt in the root of your project folder and type:

   `npm install --save @types/jquery`.

   If you are posed with a question to choose the version, choose the latest one.
2. Once the above command ends successfully, run `yarn install`.
3. Once the above install is success, run `yarn start` to start your project.