# How can I display the current app version from package.json to the user using Vite?

Tags: npm, package.json, vite

With create-react-app one could use `process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION` for this.

Is there an equivalent in Vite?

Comment: This question is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67707813/defining-global-variables-with-vite-development

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use `define` in `vite.config.js`. Read about it [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define)

**vite.config.js**

```js
export default {
    plugins: [vue()],
    define: {
        '__APP_VERSION__': JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_version),
    }
}
```

**MyComponent.vue**

```html
<script setup>
// can't be used directly on the template
const version = __APP_VERSION__
</script>
<template>
    <div>{{ version }}</div>
</template>
```

You should be able to change `'__APP_VERSION__'` as long as it doesn't conflict with javascript syntax or other variables.

### Typescript

Taken directly from [Vite Docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define)

For TypeScript users, make sure to add the type declarations in the `env.d.ts` or `vite-env.d.ts` file to get type checks and Intellisense.

**vite-env.d.ts**

```
declare const __APP_VERSION__: string
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to get this to run with React? I use `plugins: [reactRefresh()],`

Comment: ok got it, just Typescript arguing about unknown var.

Comment: @Obiwahn oh sorry, I didn't use react nor ts, my answer is purely for vite & vuejs.
It might help others if you also post react version as an answer here. :D

Comment: This made more sense when I discovered that "define" adds properties to the global window object in the browser.  So, in the above answer, you can use `window.__APP_VERSION__` in any JavaScript.

Comment: Works the same in react, just chang the plugin to the reactRefresh plugin

Comment: does it work after build on production?

Comment: @DanCZ Yes, I'm using it in all my webapps, using `npm run build`.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius I have tried and it works just on local. how can it work when package.json is not deployed? I am using Vue and Vite in my project.

Comment: @DanCZ package.json is not deployed. You just run `npm run build`, and deploy the output (by default it's the `dist` folder). Can you setup a reproduction repo so I can take a look?

Answer (score 60):

### For React & TypeScript users:

Add a `define` to your `vite.config.ts`:

```js
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    APP_VERSION: JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_version),
  },
});
```

If you haven't got one already, define a `vite-env.d.ts` or `env.d.ts` and add a `declare`:

```
declare const APP_VERSION: string;
```

You'll now be able to use the variable `APP_VERSION` anywhere in your code & Vite will substitute it at compile time.

**Note:** You may need to restart your TS server for the declaration to be picked up by intellisense:

VSCode MacOS: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> `> Restart TS Server`

VSCode Windows:  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> `> Restart TS Server`

Comment: The documentation about the define option can be found on https://vitejs.dev/config/#define. It suggests to put the Typescript declaration into a file named `env.d.ts` or `vite-env.d.ts`

Comment: This works! Thanks for the fix. It's always tricky when a TS error hits you out of nowhere

Answer (score 24):

## Vite 4, React, Typescript setup

This worked for me.

I imported `package.json` in `vite.config.ts` and defined a `PACKAGE_VERSION` environment variable.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import packageJson from './package.json';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define:  {
    'import.meta.env.PACKAGE_VERSION': JSON.stringify(packageJson.version)
  }
})
```

I added `"resolveJsonModule": true` to the compiler options of  `tsconfig.node.json`.
I added `"./package.json"` to the include array of  `tsconfig.node.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts", "./package.json"]
}
```

In order to make intellisense work for `PACKAGE_VERSION`, I added it to `vite-env.d.ts`

```ts
interface ImportMetaEnv {
    readonly PACKAGE_VERSION: string;
    // more env variables...
}
  
interface ImportMeta {
    readonly env: ImportMetaEnv
}
```

I could use `{import.meta.env.PACKAGE_VERSION}` anywhere in my react app to show the package version.

Comment: This step-by-step guide is 100% complete and worked for me in the first try. Love it.

Comment: This solution works in both development and after the build process. The other approaches only worked for me during local development, after the build PACKAGE_VERSION was undefined. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Simplest solution

```
// .env
VITE_REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version
```

```
// App.jsx
...
console.log('ver. ', import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_VERSION)
...
```

Comment: Wow. It's a magic!

Comment: Nice, so apparently the `npm_package_*` environment variables are automatically generated by npm based on the values specified in your project's `package.json` file (for example `$npm_package_name`, `$npm_package_version`). However I didn't find any documentation about this. If someone has any resources, please add it here.

Comment: The variables are created by NPM when the "scripts" are run. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use `define`, there is a vite plugin for just this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-package-version

```js
// vite.config.js
import loadVersion from 'vite-plugin-package-version';

export default {
  plugins: [loadVersion()],
};
```

Will inject import.meta.env.PACKAGE_VERSION with the version specified in your package.json.

Comment: In the end the plugin is also using a define

Comment: This is no longer working for production build. Neither will the define way work.

Comment: @SworupShakya do you know why this won't work using define?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```js
import { version } from '@/../package.json'
```

The @ was define in vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  resolve: {
    // ...
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: This might lead to security risk as stated https://stackoverflow.com/q/70298948/3671954 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/64993118/3671954

Comment: This doesn't work after application is built. It works only in `DEV` mode.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius Security risk is about `import * as packageInfo from '../../package.json'; version: packageInfo.version`, not about my answer.

Comment: @BranislavPopadič I does not use mode, but it worked for me at production environment after vite build.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is interested, this automatically increases the version in `package.json` and makes it available to the application.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
const increasePackageVersion = () => {
    try {
        const fs = require('fs');
        const path = require('path');
        const packageFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'package.json');
        const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(packageFilePath, 'utf8'));
        packageJson.version = packageJson.version.replace(/(\d+)$/, (match, p1) => {
            return parseInt(p1) + 1;
        }
        );
        fs.writeFileSync(packageFilePath, JSON.stringify(packageJson, null, 2));
        console.log('New version is', packageJson.version);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error in increasePackageVersion', error);
    }

};

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: 'src/main.js',
            formats: ['es']
        }
    },
    plugins: [
    increasePackageVersion()],
    define: {
        '__APP_VERSION__': JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_version),
    }
});
```

```js
console.log(__APP_VERSION__);
```

Comment: awesome, this is really the one i care about

Comment: do you know how i would only run this on yarn build? i notice it also runs for yarn serve

Comment: npm/yarn has cli commands that do exactly what your custom function:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-version
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/version/

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `VITE_VERSION=${npm_package_version}` in .env works for me. The version is available under `import.meta.env.VITE_VERSION`. Tested on vite version **4.4.5**.

Answer (score 1):

## React, Vite, Typescript

I have used this with React, typescript and vite.

Here is what worked for me and why:

### first step: add version

Added the version to: `vite.config.ts`

```js
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    `config.version`: JSON.stringify('my-custom-name')
  }
})
```

### declared the config file on .d.ts

This will prevent the typescript from creating an issue for not declaring global config.

On this file: `src/vite-env.d.ts`
Added the next line

```js
declare var config: any;
```

### used the variable.

I used the variable inside the react function as any normal variable:

```js
const { version } = config;
```

I used this on the open sauced project at this PR: https://github.com/open-sauced/ai/pull/141/files in case if you want to check the relevant code.

It would be helpful to reference the next questions as well:

[Angular error TS2304: Cannot find name 'config'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273495/angular-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-config)

[Create a global variable in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

### Below Answer includes

1. Secure Way of Importing Vue version.
2. Incrementing semantic versions using npm commands

[Secure  and Semantic Way of Versioning using npm and env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298948/how-to-securely-import-version-from-package-json-while-respecting-error-should/70333147#70333147)

Answer (score 0):

A previous answer suggests to add `VITE_VERSION=${npm_package_version}` to your `.env`. If you work by yourself or in a small team and you have an established way to manage `.env` files I think this is the best option. This didn't work in my case because my team pulls `.env` files from Vercel and as far as I know, Vercel variables are all saved as strings, not shell commands with variables. My team wants to reduce human interaction required to set up the local environment, so this solution doesn't work for us.

Other answers either didn't work for me or had potential security issues by exposing `package.json` to the client. I'm posting my solution in case it helps others with a similar config. I'm not sure if it's the most elegant solution but it works well in all environments and seems to avoid the problem of exposing `package.json` to the client.

Here's my config, besides the obvious (using Vite):

- using `yarn`
- React app
- deploying with Vercel

Here's what I added to `package.json`:

1. In the `scripts` section add script named `"version"` with the value `"echo $npm_package_version"`. This will output the package version. More info in NPM [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars)
2. In the `scripts` section do this for every command that includes `vite`:

   - immediately before the `vite` command in the script, create a variable prefixed with `VITE_` ([Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode#env-files:%7E:text=only%20variables%20prefixed%20with%20VITE_%20are%20exposed%20to%20your%20Vite%2Dprocessed%20code): only `VITE_` prefixed variables are exposed to client source code) and assign it the value output by the `version` script you just created. For example:

     - `"dev": "vite --port=4000",` becomes:
     - `"dev": "VITE_APP_VERSION=$(yarn run version) vite --port=4000"`

Here's the result

```json
{
  "name": "your-package-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  ....
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "version": "echo $npm_package_version",
    "dev": "VITE_APP_VERSION=$(yarn run version) vite --port=4000",
    "build": "tsc && VITE_APP_VERSION=$(yarn run version) vite build",
    "preview": "VITE_APP_VERSION=$(yarn run version) vite preview",
    ...
  }
}
```

Then, you can access the package version in your app using `import.meta.env.VITE_APP_VERSION`.

For example:

```js
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_VERSION)   // 0.1.0
```

This worked for me in local and Vercel deployments using Yarn. Hope it helps!