# defining global variables with vite development

Tags: vue.js, global-variables, vuejs3, vite

Now I am using **vite build tool** for my **vue SFC app**. I read the documentation of vite with the link below:

[vite config link](https://vitejs.dev/config/#define)

If I am not wrong, the **define** option in config could be used for defining **global constants**. What I want to do is to define for example the name of my App in a variable inside this option and then use it in my Vue components. But unfortunately there is no example of code in the documentation about this option.

I tried this code in my **vite.config.js** file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
      global: {
        appName: "my-custom-name"
      }
  },
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

I am not sure that the syntax and code is *correct*! And also if it is correct I don't know how to call (use) this constant in my vue app components (*.vue files*). For example I want to use it in **template** or **script** part of this component:

```html
<template>
    <div class="bgNow">

    <p class="color1">
{{ use here }}
    </p>

</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
              name: use here
            };
        },
        
        methods: {
            nameMethod() {
                
                
                console.log(use here);
                
            }

        } // end of method

    } // end of export
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

I declared the places that want with **"use here"** in the code. And also if there is  any other way that I could define some global constants and variables in my **vite** vue app, I very much appreciate your help to tell me about that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`define` is a config that tells Vite how to perform a search-and-replace. It can only replace one string for another (objects cannot be used as a replacement).

For example, to replace all instances of `appName` with `"my-custom-name"`, use the following config. *Note `JSON.stringify()` is used (per the [recommendation in the docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define)) to ensure the literal string replacement is properly quoted.*

```js
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    appName: JSON.stringify('my-custom-name')
  }
})
```

If `App.vue` contained:

```html
<script setup>
console.log('appName', appName)
</script>
```

It would be transformed to:

```html
<script setup>
console.log("appName", "my-custom-name")
</script>
```

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vite-define-global-demo)

Comment: The `define` section of the Vite docs has moved here: <https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define>

Comment: I used this approach in my Vue.js app + Vite 4. But the defined variable can not found!.

Comment: Tested it for Next JS as well works perfectly fine. If you are using TypeScript make sure to declare a const as stated in the docs.

Comment: Looks like replacement doesn't happen in the `<template>` section? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77133977/vite-defines-in-vue-sfc-mustaches-dont-work

Comment: Oh!. when i first read docs i though it would provide me a gloabal constant variable which i can access across my app. vite docs does not contain any example  for this that is why it can be confusing.