# Vite defines in Vue SFC mustaches don't work?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

My vite-config.ts has this.

```
export default defineConfig({
...
  define: {
    __PRODUCT__: JSON.stringify("My Product")
  }
```

My vue sfc template contains this

```
   <div class="footer">
    {{ __PRODUCT__ }}
   </div>
```

.. but I get an error `Property '__PRODUCT__' does not exist on type...`

It's fixed by having this in the `<script>` section

```
 let product = __PRODUCT__
```

... and then using  `{{product}}` in the template, but I don't understand why.