# How do I display the version number from package.json in my vue3 app?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, version, package.json, vite

I want to display the version number of my app, defined in package.json. I am using Vite, Vue 3, Typescript,  and script setup with composition API.

I solved this exact problem I had, but I have too little reputation to answer this question:

[How can I display the current app version from package.json to the user using Vite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67194082/how-can-i-display-the-current-app-version-from-package-json-to-the-user-using-vi)

So here is how to do it in Vue 3.

Use this answer as a basis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74860417/12008976.

So, add

```
import packageJson from "./package.json"
```

and

```
define: {
  'import.meta.env.PACKAGE_VERSION': JSON.stringify(packageJson.version),
},
```

to `vite.config.ts`

Add this

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

interface ImportMetaEnv {
  readonly PACKAGE_VERSION: string
}

interface ImportMeta {
  readonly env: ImportMetaEnv
}
```

to `env.d.ts` in /src

Now, this adds intellisense to `import.meta.env`. But you cannot use these import statements directly in a Vue component. I fixed it by using the [globalProperties](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties) of the Vue app.

Add

```
app.config.globalProperties.versionNumber = import.meta.env.PACKAGE_VERSION
```

to `main.ts`

Now, in a component, add

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const version = getCurrentInstance()?.appContext.config.globalProperties.versionNumber
</script>
```

```html
<div>{{ version }}</div>
```

My question is: is this the best way to solve this in Vue 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was asking the same question, and most of the solutions were similar to what you have mentioned, but then I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75607776/5596871).

Add new variable to your `.env` file:

```
VITE_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version
```

and then you can use it in your app:

```
const version = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_VERSION
```

However I did not find any documentation on how the `$npm_package_*` variables work, but apparently they are automatically populated from your `package.json` file.
If you find any resources, please add it here.

Comment: The variables are created by NPM when the "scripts" are run. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars

Comment: Thanks @scipilot, that was exactly what I was looking for.